# Proving invariance along solutions

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials

Consider the equation $$\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\phi+\frac{g}{L}\sin\phi=0$$ $L>0$ and $g>0$ is the gravity constant.

Take $x_{1}=\phi$ and $x_{2}=\frac{d}{dt}\phi$, then we have $$-\frac{g}{L}\cos x_{1}+\frac{1}{2}x_{2}^{2}$$

I want to prove that the above is invariant along solutions. The problem is that I don't know what that means exactly. I understand that if something is invariant with respect to a transformation that it remains unchanged, but in this instance I do not know.

Edit 1:

Define $V:=-\frac{g}{L}\cos x_{1}+\frac{1}{2}x_{2}^{2}$, with derivative given by $(\nabla V)(x(t))\cdot f(x(t))$, where $\nabla V=(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{1}}, \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{2}})$.

Then if $\overset{\bullet}{V}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by $\overset{\bullet}{V}:=\nabla V\cdot f$ is zero, then $V(x(\cdot))$ is neither increasing nor decreasing and is thus invariant along solutions.

Is that right? Then what would I take as $f$? I can calculate $\nabla V=(\frac{g}{L}\sin x_{1}, x_{2})$

Comment: It seems that it means it's independent of $t$.

Comment: @JohnMa I think I might have it. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to show that $$\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac 12 \left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2-\frac gL \cos \phi\right)=0.$$ We have that

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac 12 \left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2-\frac gL \cos \phi\right) & \\  & =\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}\frac{d\phi}{dt}+\frac gL \sin \phi \frac{d\phi}{dt} \\  & =\left(\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}+\frac gL \sin \phi\right) \frac{d\phi}{dt}\\  & \underbrace{=}_{\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}+\frac gL \sin \phi=0}0\cdot \frac{d\phi}{dt} \\  & =0. \end{align}$$